# best way to create padding between inline elements

Tags: html, css, xhtml, inline

I'm relatively new to css but I was wondering what's the best way to create some padding between images.  Say for example, I have a series of three thumbnails that I want on the same line.  I want 10px of padding between each.  I tried floating them but then all of the following inline elements appear on the same line.

Comment: code example of what you are talking about/have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to do it would be to use an un-ordered list and set `margin-left` to the list item. Something like:

**CSS:**

```
ul.thumbnails{
overflow:hidden;
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}

ul.thumbnails li{
float:left;
margin-left:10px;
}

ul.thumbnails li:first-child{
margin-left:0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
<li><img src="path/to/image" /></li>
<li><img src="path/to/image" /></li>
<li><img src="path/to/image" /></li>
<li><img src="path/to/image" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Instead of `margin-right`/`:last-child`, you should use `margin-left`/`:first-child`. `:first-child` works in IE7/8, whereas `:last-child` doesn't. Indeed, I wrote `margin-left` in my own answer in the first place because I was thinking of this.

Comment: Of course. Thanks for that thirthydot. I'll update my answer =)

Comment: @Dan:  Works perfectly!  Can you explain what it specifically in the CSS that prevents inline elements (for example, text) that follow from wrapping around the images?

Comment: @Dan: also, Aptana says that property list item `none` doesn't exist and a bullet shows up between the images.  Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry @sq1020, I was typing on the fly. I will fix the list-item typo. It was supposed to be list-style:none;. Basically, the overflow:hidden; on the UL is clearing the floated LI's. When you float an element, you need to clear the float. There are a number of ways to clear the float but overflow:hidden; works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

You could add some `margin` to your images:

```
#containerOfImages img {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```